# Determine the spectral decomposition of $\frac{d}{dx}\in \mathcal{L}(V)$ in terms of an inner product.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am asked the following

> Define an inner product on the vector space $V=span\{e^x,e^{2x},e^{3x}\}$ and write out the spectral decomposition of $\frac{d}{dx}\in \mathcal{L}(V)$ in terms of an inner product.

---

I think the inner product $ \langle x^m | x^n \rangle=\delta_{m,n}$, where $\delta_{m,n}$ is the Kronecker delta, makes a nice inner product for this particular vector space.

However, I'm not sure where to begin decomposing the operator $\frac{d}{dx}$ on the vector space. 
Just to get my ideas out, right or wrong; here is where my head is:

1. We need to find an orthonormal basis of different eigenvectors. By definition if we are to decompose this operator, the operator must be diagonalizable. Hence, there exists a orthonormal basis consisting of eigenvectors.
2. Is the adjoint of $\frac{d}{dx}=-\frac{d}{dx}$? Is it necessary to consider the adjoint for this problem?
3. Is the field over $\frac{d}{dx}$ assumed to be $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$?

Can anyone guide me through this problem and correct any mistakes I've made in the statements above?

Answer (score 0):

Observe $\langle x^m,x^n\rangle=\delta_{m,n}$ is not an inner product on $\mathrm{span}\{e^x,e^{2x},e^{3x}\}$; you're defining an inner product on a completely different vector space.

Given any basis $\{v_i\}$ for a real or complex vector space $V$, we can define an inner product on it via the relations $\langle v_i,v_j\rangle=\delta_{ij}$, so in this case we should treat $\{e^x,e^{2x},e^{3x}\}$ as a basis and define

$$\langle a_1e^x+a_2e^{2x}+a_3e^{3x},b_1e^x+b_2e^{2x}+b_3e^{3x}\rangle:=a_1\overline{b_1}+a_2\overline{b_2}+a_3\overline{b_3}.$$

Ignore the bars if the scalar field is $\mathbb{R}$.

(1) What happens when you apply $\frac{d}{dx}$ to the basis vectors $e^x$, $e^{2x}$, $e^{3x}$?

(2) Actually it looks like $\frac{d}{dx}$ is self-adjoint. Prove this.

(3) I don't think it matters, but I'd assume $\mathbb{R}$ because of the exponentials.